# PHP which version supports simplexml cdata

Tags: php, version, simplexml, cdata

From which PHP 5 version does simplexml_load_file support CDATA?

```
 $xml = @simplexml_load_file($url, NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You're contradicting yourself a little here; you want CDATA support, yet you've set the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` flag?

Comment: i believe the LIBXML_NOCDATA prevents the cdata from being escaped and left out of the object. see: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php#85484

Comment: The CDATA is not "left out of the object", it is just not visible in `var_dump`, `print_r`, etc, causing confusion. There is no need to pass `LIBXML_NOCDATA` in order to work with SimpleXML in the normal way; for an explanation of what it actually does, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13981917/157957

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure this answers your question (some clarity might help?) but I found this at php.net:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php#82067

"A PHP version >= 5.1.0 is required for this to work"

Comment: Does it also support CDATA from that version?

Comment: the only thing that is clear to me is that 5.1 is required to include the CDATA in the object. I'm not sure what happens when using php < 5.1.

Comment: PHP 5.1 is required to support the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` option; it is **not** required to include the CDATA in the object, becase the CDATA is always there - it's just not visible in `var_dump`, `print_r`, etc

Answer (score 1):

As in http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php said, I think from PHP version >= 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML supports CDATA in **any** version, and there is no need to pass `LIBXML_NOCDATA`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13830559/157957 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16842431/157957