# Get a special charactor in a XML file using simplexml and CDATA

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, cdata

I am trying to retreive a string in a XML file using simplexml. But the string contains the character "&". So I think I have to use CDATA to get the value. I am really new to this and don't no how to do it.
this is just an example of what I want.

Example.php

```
<?php
  $xmlstr = <<<XML
  <?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
  <Books>
     <Book>
        <title> PHP & XML </title>
        <author> Some text </author>
        <price> Some text </price>
     </Book>
     <Book>
        <title> Java & Coding </title>
        <author> Some text </author>
        <price> Some text </price>
     </Book>

  </Books>
  XML;
?>
```

And this is my calling php file

call.php

```
<?php
  include 'Example.php';

  $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
  $abc = $xml->Book[0]->title[0];
  echo $abc;
?>
```

And it is giving an error because of the character "&". I cannot change my XML. Any modification can be done to call.php
Any help regarding the matter would be highly appreciate.
Thanx.

Comment: Well, the XML is technically invalid. You *should* and *need* to change it.

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you tell me which part of my XML is invalid?

Comment: The `&`. No bare `&` is allowed in bare text nodes, it is *required* to be `&amp;`.

Comment: Yes that is my problem. I cannot change it. So when I retrieve the string inside <title> tag, I have to come up with a way. Do you have any idea how to do that. I cannot change my Example.php as it is not accessible to me. I only can do changes to call.php

Comment: Thank you for your help. I sort it out with the help from @NullVoid :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an exact question like this SO [PHP, SimpleXML, decoding entities in CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979582/php-simplexml-decoding-entities-in-cdata?rq=1)

It has explain about CDATA which can be used in case of

> special characters (in particular, >, < and &) to be escaped. A CDATA
>   section containing the character & is the same as a normal text node
>   containing &.

Have a look on this.

**Edit**

Here is one solution if you load every time your example.php code into string then below is one solution.

```
  $xmlstr = str_replace("&","&amp;",$xmlstr);
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
  $abc = $xml->Book[0]->title[0];
  echo $abc;
```

Comment: Yes I know how to use CDATA inside a XML
    <title> PHP <![CDATA[ & ]]> XML </title>
But my problem is how can I use it in my call.php as I cannot do any changes to my Example.php