# SimpleXML: handle CDATA tag presence in node value

Tags: php, simplexml, cdata

I need to save `<![CDATA[]]>` tag when I parse XML document.

For example, I have node:

```
<Dest><![CDATA[some text...]]></Dest>
```

In xml file may be present nodes without CDATA.

Then I process all the nodes in loop:

```
$dom = simplexml_load_file($path);
foreach($dom->children() as $child) {
 $nodeValue = (string) $child;
}
```

As a result, when I process node in example above - `$nodeValue` = `some text...`

But I need `$nodeValue` = `<![CDATA[some text...]]>`

There is any way to do this?

File example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <Params>
    <param>text</param>
    <anotherParam>text</anotherParam>
  </Params>
  <Content>
    <String>
      <Source>some another text</Source>
      <Dest>some another text 2</Dest>
    </String>
    <String>
      <Source>some another text 3</Source>
      <Dest><![CDATA[some text...]]></Dest>
    </String>
  </Content>
</Root>
```

Comment: Can you give an exemple of a XML file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as a parser like SimpleXML is concerned, the `<![CDATA[` is not part of the text content of the XML element, it's just part of the serialization of that content. A similar confusion is discussed here: [PHP, SimpleXML, decoding entities in CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979582/php-simplexml-decoding-entities-in-cdata/13981917#13981917)

What you need to look at is the "inner XML" of that element, which is tricky in SimpleXML (`->asXML()` will give you the "outer XML", e.g. `<Dest><![CDATA[some text...]]></Dest>`).

Your best bet here is to use [the DOM](http://php.net/dom) which gives you more access to the detailed *structure* of the document, rather than trying to give you the *content*, so distinguishes "text nodes" and "CDATA nodes". However, it's worth double-checking that you do actually need this, as for 99.9% of use cases, you shouldn't care whether somebody sent you `<foo>bar &amp; baz</foo>` or `<foo><![CDATA[bar & baz]]></foo>`, since by definition they represent the same string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add CDATA to all element who doesn't have it, you can do that :

```
$dom = simplexml_load_file($path);
foreach($dom->children() as $child) {
     if(strpos((string) $child,'CDATA')){
         $nodeValue = (string) $child)
     }
     else {
         $nodeValue = "<![CDATA[".((string) $child)."]]>";
     }
 }
```

with that you will have `$nodeValue = '<![CDATA[some text...]]>'`

if you want to just have the element where there is CDATA you can do that :

```
$dom = simplexml_load_file($path);
foreach($dom->children() as $child) {
     if(strpos((string) $child,'CDATA')){
         $nodeValue = (string) $child;
     }
 }
```

with that you will have `$nodeValue = '<![CDATA[some text...]]>'`

if you want the element without CDATA and add it you can do that :

```
$dom = simplexml_load_file($path);
foreach($dom->children() as $child) {
     if(!strpos((string) $child,'CDATA')){
         $notValue ="<![CDATA[".((string) $child)."]]>";
     }
 }
```

with that you wil have `$nodeValue = '<![CDATA[some another text 3]]>'`

Comment: In xml file may be present nodes without CDATA

Comment: How do you know wich have has to have CDATA and wich one doesn't ?

Comment: @AndrewAndrew Oh, you have an xml file where some of the value are `<![CDATA[some text...]]>` and with your algo it deletes the CDATA ?

Comment: When I parse xml-file I don't know anything about file structure etc. Some nodes may have CDATA, some may haven't, I can't know that. But while parsing, I need to handle it

Comment: @AndrewAndrew Ok so if node Contains CDATA you just rewrite it, if not, you add CDATA ?

Comment: If node contains CDATA, in some way I will process it

Comment: @AndrewAndrew I don't quit understand what you want so i gave you 3 possibilities. Try to see if what you need is in there

Comment: @AndrewAndrew Why ?

Comment: Because `(string) $child` no longer has tag CDATA. SimpleXML skip it

Comment: @AndrewAndrew Do you realise what you are asking is not very clear? Wich one do you talk about ? the first or the second one ? If that is the second one, whatd do you want to do when there is no CDATA ?