# SimpleXML converts html entities

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the XML file that contains some html entities in node content. Example:

```
...
<node>node&apos;s content</node>
...
```

When I load file by SimpleXML (using `simplexml_load_file` method), node content is being converted automatically to `node's content`

When I specify LIBXML_NOENT in simplexml_load_file - nothing happens, HTML entities still be parsed.

How to save original node content?

Comment: Unless you specify the `LIBXML_NOENT` HTML entities shouldn't be parsed. Can you show more code?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how entities work, and what they represent - the string content of that element *is* "node's content", the `&apos;` is just how that's written into the XML. If you output the element back as XML, you'll see the `&apos;` again. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979582/php-simplexml-decoding-entities-in-cdata/13981917#13981917) to a somewhat related question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can add a parameter to `simplexml_load_file()` that keeps it from substituting HTML entities. See http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php.

```
SimpleXMLElement xml = simplexml_load_file("myFile", "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOENT(0));
```

Comment: Call to undefined function LIBXML_NOENT()

Comment: LIBXML_NOENT is a constant, not a function, so miss off the (0) bit.

Comment: When I specify only LIBXML_NOENT - nothing happens, HTML entities still be parsed