# SimpleXML PHP - save <br></br> instead of &lt;br&gt;&lt;/br&gt;

Tags: php

i'm using [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) in order to change the value of a text node which could also contain HTML.

The issue i'm facing is that whenever I save a value like:

```
test<br></br>
```

in the xml file it gets saved as

```
test&lt;br&gt;&lt;/br&gt;
```

In order to edit the text value i'm using the following code:

```
<?php

    $new_description = $_POST['description']; //get input text

    $xml_description = simplexml_load_file("path_to_file.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    $formatted_description = str_replace("<br />", "<br></br>", nl2br($new_description));
    $xml_description->channel->item->description = html_entity_decode($formatted_description, null, 'utf-8');

    $xml_description->asXML("path_to_file.xml");

?>
```

Is there any way to avoid the encoding or should I change library?

Comment: _“the value of a text node which could also contain HTML”_ - it _either_ is a text node, _or_ it contains HTML.

Comment: If `test<br></br>` should be the content of that node, then saving it as `test&lt;br&gt;&lt;/br&gt;` in XML is correct. What is the problem you have with that? Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you want to do. Also add the content of "path_to_file.xml" to your question and what you want to do. Basically add a [mcve].

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979582/php-simplexml-decoding-entities-in-cdata/13981917#13981917 gives an idea about using CDATA

Answer (score 0):

you can just re-replace them:

```
str_replace(
    "&lt;br&gt;&lt;/br&gt;", 
    "<br></br>",
    html_entity_decode($formatted_description, null, 'utf-8')
);
```

Or if you have a lot of those that you need to ignore, and they can be separated:

```
$str = html_entity_decode($formatted_description, null, 'utf-8');
$to_reset = [
    '&lt;br&gt;' => '<br>',
    '&lt;/br&gt;' => '</br>',
];
foreach($to_reset as $k => $v){
    $str = str_replace(
        $k, 
        $v,
        html_entity_decode($str, null, 'utf-8')
    );
}
```