# simplexml_load_file is missing data in Wordpress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

Loading a Wordpress RSS feed to embed it on another website in PHP.

```
simplexml_load_file('http://blog.sporttoury.com/feed');
```

But I can't get image, category or text of the post.

```
SimpleXMLElement {#955 ▼
  +"title": "Website. Description of the website"
  +"link": "http://blog.website.com/liktothepost"
  +"pubDate": "Fri, 17 Feb 2017 07:56:43 +0000"
  +"category": SimpleXMLElement {#1131}
  +"guid": "http://blog.website.com/?p=400"
  +"description": SimpleXMLElement {#953}
}
```

Any idea of what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, data is there but it is not visible with `print_r`, `var_dump` or just `dump` in Twig. I found the solution here: [Reading text in `<![CDATA[...]]>` with SimpleXMLElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835287/reading-text-in-cdata-with-simplexmlelement)