# php simplexml_load_file and CDATA has data missing completely

Tags: php

I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<data>
   <item name="general.global.Event"><![CDATA[EVENT!]]></item>
   <item name="general.global.CompanyName"><![CDATA[some name]]></item>
   <item name="general.global.CompanyImprint"><![CDATA[Legal information]]></item>
</data>
```

and my code is as follows

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("general.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
```

and my output is missing the CDATA.. how?

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[item] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => general.global.Event
                    )

            )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => general.global.CompanyName
                    )

            )

        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => general.global.CompanyImprint
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDATA is being read, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16842431/629157) and you'll see that if you `print_r($xml->asXML())`; The parser recompiles the CDATA information just fine.

For some reason, PHP's `var_dump` and `print_r` don't have accurate representation of XML objects. Try this and you can still access the data:

```
foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
    if ('general.global.CompanyImprint' === (string)$item['name']) {
        var_dump((string)$item);
    }
}

// prints

string(17) "Legal information"
```

Answer (score 3):

Text nodes are not exposed with `print_r`.

You can see the data there is you look at it explicitly:

```
print $xml->item[0];
```