# Could not to read data from xml file due to that tag <![CDATA[]]

Tags: php, xml

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"
>

    <item>
        <title>Hello world!</title>
        <link>http://localhost/wordpress/?p=1</link>
        <category><![CDATA[Uncategorized]]></category>
        <HEADLINE><![CDATA[Does Sleep Apnea Offer Some Protection During Heart Attack?]]></HEADLINE>
    </item>
</rss>
```

**i used that code read xml file**

```
    <?php
      if (file_exists('test.xml')) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
          echo "<pre>";
          print_r($xml);
          echo "</pre>";
      } else {
         exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
         }
     ?>
```

**Output**

```
      SimpleXMLElement Object
 (
 [@attributes] => Array
    (
        [version] => 2.0
    )

[item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [title] => Hello world!
        [link] => http://localhost/wordpress/?p=1
        [category] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [HEADLINE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

    )

 )
```

**but i have problem with those tag in xml**

```
        <category><![CDATA[Uncategorized]]></category>
    <HEADLINE><![CDATA[Does Sleep Apnea Offer Some Protection During Heart Attack?]]></HEADLINE>

 to read data bcoz of it <![CDATA[]] in category and HEADLINE
```

**i need output**

```
        SimpleXMLElement Object
   (
 [@attributes] => Array
    (
        [version] => 2.0
    )

[item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [title] => Hello world!
        [link] => http://localhost/wordpress/?p=1
        [category] => Uncategorized
        [HEADLINE] => Does Sleep Apnea Offer Some Protection During Heart Attack?
    )

 )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting cdata content while parsing xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650203/getting-cdata-content-while-parsing-xml-file)

Comment: How about `$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml','SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);`

Comment: why my question down voted, may i know the reason?

Comment: I have no clue, but this was happening to me all day yesterday and I was trying all sorts of thing.  First thing this morning I realized it could be the cdata, and I found this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this when loading the file

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($this->filename,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply this:

```
var_dump(
    (string)$xml->item->category,
    (string)$xml->item->HEADLINE
);
```

It's worth nothing that SimpleXML builds stuff on the fly so `print_r()` on objects does not necessarily display useful info.

Answer (score -1):

try casting the

```
[category] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [HEADLINE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )
```

to strings, and i think you will get what you need

```
$item['category']=(string)$item['category'];
```