# Response with raw PDF could not be parsed as XML

Tags: php, xml

I recieve an XML-response from an API that looks something like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<tppxmlresponse>
<requestvalid>1</requestvalid>
<invoicevalid>1</invoicevalid>
<invoicepdf><![CDATA[%PDF-1.3
%“Œ‹ž ReportLab Generated PDF document http://www.reportlab.com
% 'BasicFonts': class PDFDictionary 
1 0 obj
% The standard fonts dictionary
<< /F1 2 0 R
 /F2 3 0 R
 /F3+0 11 0 R >>
endobj
(....)
startxref
110364
%%EOF
]]></invoicepdf></tppxmlresponse>
```

`<invoicepdf>` contains raw PDF that I'm looking to fetch. But using the regular `new SimpleXMLElement($response);` on the response returns the following error;

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in (...)
```

Any ideas to best access the contents of `<invoicepdf>`, stripping away the XML, would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried sending the XML through an XML-Validator just to be sure it's not malformed?

Comment: Hah, it doesnt validate. Seems to be a tag-character in the middle of the raw pdf-mess. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting cdata content while parsing xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650203/getting-cdata-content-while-parsing-xml-file)